# Split variable and push into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a variable that contains a few comma seperated values. I'd like to split these up and push them into an array as integers only I can't figure it out.

I've the following...

```
globArr = [];
arr = "1,4,3,2,4,2,4";

var answ = arr.split(',');
globArr.push(parseInt(answ));

console.log(globArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d7hke7gq/

Can anybody tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: `arr = "1,4,3,2,4,2,4";var answ = arr.split(',');console.log(answ);`. very simple

Comment: what should `parseInt` do in this context? getting a number or getting an integer number?

Comment: `globArr = [];
var arr = "1,4,3,2,4,2,4";
var answ = arr.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < answ.length; i++)
{
    globArr.push(parseInt(answ[i]));
    console.log(answ[i]);
}

console.log(globArr);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over answ array for pushing each value:

```js
let globArr = [];
let arr = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
let answ = arr.split(',');
answ.forEach(function(obj){
      globArr.push(parseInt(obj,10));
});
console.log(globArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7hke7gq/)

```
globArr = [];
arr = "1,4,3,2,4,2,4";

var answ = arr.split(',');
$.each(answ, function(){
globArr.push(parseInt(this));
});


console.log(globArr);
```